# TFS crashed, new server but workspace does still exist

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, workspace

Our TFS was crashed, and we setup a new TFS with the same name, but with another defaultcollection name.

After setting up the new tfs, i want to connect using the same mapping. Our workspaces are not local, but server side.

The strangest thing is that i keep getting the error:

> The path d:\teamfs is already mapped in workspace [myname] [http://teamfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection].

But this defaultcollection does not exist anymore, the new one is called 'dotnet'.
Locally there is no workspace with this name.

Using the tf.exe also does nothing:

> tf.exe workspace /owner:*

does reply:

> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server teamfs\DefaultC
>   ollection.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     Page not found.

How to get rid of this workspace from my local machine? Because the teamfs\DefaultCollection does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you force the deletion of a TFS 2010 workspace on a client when the TFS Server no longer exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297710/how-do-you-force-the-deletion-of-a-tfs-2010-workspace-on-a-client-when-the-tfs-s)  -  you'll need to delete this workspace from the local workspace cache.

Comment: Hi Edward, thanks for the reply. Indeed that is the same problem. I'm just wondering why i did not find that answer... Sorry for that...

Comment: This post is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297710/how-do-you-force-the-deletion-of-a-tfs-2010-workspace-on-a-client-when-the-tfs-s

Comment: Dennis - glad that fixed your problem!